# How do you check if a given input is a palindrome?

Tags: list-comprehension, palindrome

I need to check if the input is a palindrome.

I converted the input to a string and compared the input with the reverse of the input using list slicing. I want to learn a different way without converting input to a string.

```
def palindrome(n):
   num = str(n)
   if num == num[::-1]:
      return True
```

Comment: Is the input a string? Or is it a number?

Comment: @Ajaff, I just added an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `n` is a number, you can get digits from right to left and build a number with those digits from left to right:

```
n = 3102
m = n
p = 0
while m:
     p = p*10 + m%10 # add the rightmost digit of m to the right of p
     m //= 10 # remove the rightmost digit of m

print(p) # 2013
```

Hence the function:

```
def palindrome(n):
    m = n
    p = 0
    while m:
         p = p*10 + m%10
         m //= 10
    return p == n
```

Note that:

```
if num == num[::-1]:
    return True
```

will return `None` if `num != num[::-1]` (end of the function). You should write:

```
if num == num[::-1]:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Or (shorter and cleaner):

```
return num == num[::-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

There can be 2 more approaches to that as follows:

> - Iterative Method: Run loop from starting to length/2 and check first character to last character of string and second to second last one and so on. If any character mismatches, the string wouldn’t be palindrome.

Sample Code Below:

```
def isPalindrome(str):  
    for i in xrange(0, len(str)/2):  
        if str[i] != str[len(str)-i-1]: 
            return False
    return True
```

> - One Extra Variable Method: In this method, user take a character of string one by one and store in a empty variable. After storing all the character user will compare both the string and check whether it is palindrome or not.

Sample Code Below:

```
def isPalindrome(str):  
    w = "" 

    for i in str: 
        w = i + w 

    if (str==w): 
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following approach:

1. Extract all the digits from the number `n`
2. In each iteration, append the digit to one list (`digits`) and at that digit at the beginning of another list (`reversed_digits`)
3. Once all digits have been extracted, compare both lists

```py
def palindrome(n):
    digits = []
    reversed_digits = []
    while n > 0:
        digit = n % 10
        digits.append(digit)
        reversed_digits.insert(0, digit)
        n //= 10
    return digits == reversed_digits
```

Note: this might not be the most efficient way to solve this problem, but I think it is very easy to understand.